# Batch request Bing Maps Route API from within Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, bing-maps

My question centres on using a batch request to resolve the distance between a single postcode in relation to many others, using the Microsoft Bing Maps API within a Microsoft Access database.

I have two tables within the database, `I_BasePostcode` and `I_Postcodes`. The `I_BasePostcode` holds a single postcode for a point of interest (a hospital in this case) and the `I_Postcodes` hold thousands (up to 30,000) of other postcodes as well as their respective distances from the `I_BasePostcode`.

The `I_BasePostcode` looks like:

```
+----------+
| Postcode |
+----------+
| LS1 3EX  |
+----------+
```

and an extract from the `I_Postcodes` table looks like:

```
+----------+--------------------+
| Postcode | DistanceFromBase   |
+----------+--------------------+
| SW13 9EE |                200 |
| SW13 9EF |                201 |
| SW13 9EP |                205 |
+----------+--------------------+
```

The VBA code which makes this possible is:

```
Const BASEURL As String = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving"
Const BINGKEY As String = "It's a secret"

Public Function GetDistance(FirstLocation As String, SecondLocation As String)

    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim EditedLocation As String

    ' Parse the JSON output
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(HttpRequestToBing(FirstLocation, SecondLocation))

    ' If we get an error on the first pass it's because of Bing not liking 8 digit postcodes
    If JSON("statusCode") <> 200 Then
        If Len(SecondLocation) = 8 Then
            EditedLocation = Left(SecondLocation, 4)
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(HttpRequestToBing(FirstLocation, EditedLocation))
        End If
        If Len(SecondLocation) = 7 Then
            EditedLocation = Left(SecondLocation, 3)
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(HttpRequestToBing(FirstLocation, EditedLocation))
        End If
    End If

    ' Catch any errors from the second pass
    If JSON("statusCode") <> 200 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

    ' Nasty Bing JSON formatting makes accessing the distance difficult
    GetDistance = Trim(JSON("resourceSets")(1)("resources")(1)("travelDistance"))

    Exit Function

ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = ""

End Function

Function HttpRequestToBing(FirstLocation As String, SecondLocation As String)

    Dim BingURL As String
    Dim http As Object

    ' Setup the Map URL
    BingURL = BASEURL & "?wp.0=" & URLEncode(FirstLocation) & "&wp.1=" & URLEncode(SecondLocation) & "&avoid=minimizeTolls&du=mi&key=" & BINGKEY

    ' Setup the request and authorization
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", BingURL, False
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    http.send

    HttpRequestToBing = http.responseText

End Function
```

Please note I have some additional modules which parse the JSON output which are not part of the scope of my question and I've not included them.

Finally, the query I use to match the postcodes in `I_Postcodes` to Microsoft Bing is:

```
UPDATE I_Postcodes, I_BasePostcode 
SET I_Postcodes.DistanceFromBase = GetDistance([I_BasePostcode].[Postcode],[I_Postcodes].[Postcode])
WHERE (((I_Postcodes.DistanceFromBase) Is Null));
```

Whilst my query works, it takes about 50 minutes to parse 9,000 postcodes and I'm wondering if there is a way this can be batched to be more efficient?

Comment: I would assume that the vast majority of the 1/3 second per postcode is spent waiting for the HTTP request to return. I don't think there is anything you can do about this.

Comment: Yes you're right, but is there a way it could be batched to send like 1,000 postcodes over in one go?